# How to directly use Twilio TURN server for Android (Server, Client)

Tags: android, twilio, rtsp, p2p, turn

I have [libstreaming](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming/blob/master/src/net/majorkernelpanic/streaming/rtsp/RtspServer.java) [RTSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol) server on Android device (open some port and wait for client [p2p connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer)).
I'm able to connect to the server via local network. For outside [p2p connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer) I have to use [STUN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN) / [TURN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traversal_Using_Relays_around_NAT).
I read a lot about [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com). They wrote about [TURN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traversal_Using_Relays_around_NAT) server: [NETWORK TRAVERSAL](https://www.twilio.com/stun-turn), but didn't actually provide clear example of how to use it. They have some ready solutions I don't need.
Is it possible to use [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com) directly as [TURN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traversal_Using_Relays_around_NAT) server for video streaming, without any additional functionality?
If no, what alternatives I have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In order to use the TURN server you need to [generate an access token](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/stun-turn) which then contains all the details of the Network Traversal Service servers with credentials for accessing them.

You will need a server with which to generate this token, so that you don't expose your Twilio account credentials. The server will need to make a request to Twilio to generate the token. In curl, this would look like this:

```
$ curl -XPOST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID/Tokens.json \
    -u "YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID:YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN
```

The response then looks like this:

```
{
    "account_sid": "YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID",
    "date_created": "Mon, 17 Nov 2014 23:55:19 +0000",
    "date_updated": "Mon, 17 Nov 2014 23:55:19 +0000",
    "ice_servers": [
        {
            "url": "stun:global.stun.twilio.com:3478?transport=udp"
        },
        {
            "credential": "M87Dd74GbNfyrAydvEKiDR43go52fo6ldoJBHB6gim0=",
            "url": "turn:global.turn.twilio.com:3478?transport=udp",
            "username": "b759d275ddc641cd379f329882abe3c0618c8afdfc5e24be1b4d59482244240f"
        }
    ],
    "password": "M87Dd74GbNfyrAydvEKiDR43go52fo6ldoJBHB6gim0=",
    "registrars": null,
    "ttl": "86400",
    "username": "b759d275ddc641cd379f329882abe3c0618c8afdfc5e24be1b4d59482244240f"
}
```

You can then use the TURN server URL and credentials to access the TURN service. [Check out the documentation for this here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/stun-turn).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. For now I use twilio programmable video (generate token, connect to the room, get Participants media). Ideally I want to use my RTSP streaming ([libstreaming](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming)) and twilio TURN server, so I'll try your suggestion. But if programmable video will be free or cheap, I keep it.